Prove that there are no more than 10 consecutive primes in an arithmetic progression with common difference smaller than 2000

Given an arithmetic progression of integers $h$, $h+k$, ... , $h+nk$, ... where $0<k<2000$. If $h+nk$ is prime for $n=t,\;t+1,...,\;t+r$ prove that $r\leq 9$.

I think that this is equivalent to say that if $0<k<2000$ and $p$ is prime then there is atleast a composite number in $S_{p,k}=\{p+k,\;p+2k, ... , p+10k\}$. This is obivious true for $p\in \{2,3,5,7\}$ because $p+pk\in S_{p,k}$ and $p|(p+pk)$.
If $p\geq 11$ the statement is true when $k$ is odd (because $2|(p+k)$) or $p|k$ (because $p|(p+k)$).
I'm stuck here. My assumption at this point (if everything is right) are that $p\geq 11$ and $k$ is not a multiple of 2 or $p$ but I don't know how to go on.
Can you please give me some hint or reference?

Hint:  $2\times 3\times 5\times 7\times 11>2000$.

@lulu To check, I don't think that alone is sufficient. I'm left with the case of $ 11 \mid h, 210 \mid k$, and it's not clear to me what else can be done.

@CalvinLin  Yeah, that one case needs some fiddling.  Of course, you may as well take $h=11$ and $k=210n$ for $n\in {1,\cdots, 9}$ so you can just check.

@CalvinLin  it almost works to just look at divisibility by $13$.  That works in every case except $k=210\times 6$, and $11+210\times 6=31\times 41$.

@lulu Ah! I forget it's $h = 11$. Thanks!

Yes, you just have to rule out first term $11$ and common difference a multiple of
$210$ but less than $2000$.
